# Расскажите о данном способе вывода в консоль

Tags: c++, консоль, вывод, буферизация

Столкнулся вот с таким способом вывода в консоль (его использовали вместо обычного `cout<<`, аргументируя это тем, что он быстрее):

```
wchar_t *screen = new wchar_t[nScreenWidth*nScreenHeight + 1]; // Массив для записи в буфер
HANDLE hConsole = CreateConsoleScreenBuffer(GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, CONSOLE_TEXTMODE_BUFFER, NULL); // Буфер экрана
SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer(hConsole); // Настройка консоли
DWORD dwBytesWritten = 0; // Для дебага

screen[nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight] = '\0';  // Последний символ - окончание строки
WriteConsoleOutputCharacter(hConsole, screen, nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight, { 0, 0 }, &dwBytesWritten); // Запись в буфер
```

Я с ним не знаком и хотелось бы увидеть подробный разбор, буду очень благодарен :)
Пытался погуглить, вышло не очень.

Если что, код вот из этой статьи (для контекста): http://ilinblog.ru/article.php?id_article=49

Answer (score 0):

Рассказываю, (я вам в этой теме не до конца прошарен но отвечу) всё на самом деле довольно просто!

1. 1 строка и вправду создаёт массив для записи в буфер, но отсюда вытекает вопрос

> что за буфер?

Буфер экрана - это своего рода тоже массив (или точнее вектор зависящий от размеров окна).
На 2 строке создаётся обращение к массиву буфера, то есть к тексту, что потом будет на экране!
Это легко доказать просто выдели пустые места в консоли.
На 3 строке через

```
SetConsoleActiveScreenBuffer
```

идёт разрешение на доступ к массиву (как-то так, но это не точно. НО без этого работать не будет)
Дебаг на 4 строке есть дебаг тут всё понятно!

```
screen[nScreenWidth * nScreenHeight] = '\0';
```

здесь мы указываем последний символ для того чтоб был перенос символов и текст не улетал за экран!
А последняя это запись в наш массив буфера и автоматическое обновление! =>
Мы имеем мгновенное изменение элементов текста в консоли и запись из 1 массива с информацией в другой буферный с авто обновлением!
(это не 100% инфа это только как я сам понял этот код)

Comment: Я более-менее поправил опечатки, единственно не понял, чья мама имеется в виду в первом предложении)

Comment: там не мам а вам т9 исправил я с телефона в машине писал

Comment: мне показалось что "сам"